# Jtidy - How to preserve space between inline elements

Tags: java, docx4j, jtidy

My Html source like this

```
<p><strong><span>Hello</span></strong> <strong><span>World</span></strong></p>
```

The output got like this after conversion(without space):- **HelloWorld**

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: preserve space after cleaning html using jtidy

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **&nbsp** instead of the space?